# svn+apache per directory access control - disable root from modifying permissions file

Tags: linux, svn, apache, permissions

I currently have an svn server running on a machine to which multiple users have root access. For the svn repository I want to use per-directory access control. So I user the mod_dav module with apache and specify permissions in /etc/svn-access-file
The problem is that since multiple users have root access, then can potentially modify this file to access content that they shouldn't be able to. Is there a way to restrict access or prevent users from modifying the svn-access-file without disabling root access for everyone else?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it to be readonly, then users will need to set rw before modifying. That will deal with accidents, but not with determined users. As soon as user is root all bets are off.

Comment: Additionally, on some filesystems (ext2-4, xfs), `chattr +i` will cause a file to become immutable, which is yet another flag that needs to be reverted before writes are allowed.

Comment: Guess I will have to go with the readonly option. BTW, is there a way that I can be notified every time a file is modified?

Comment: You can set up a simple cron script and compare checksums every time. Not sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Any user who can become root has absolute power over the system. That's why you shouldn't be handing out root user privileges to people for free. A better idea would be to restrict the privilege level of the other users (assuming you are authorized to do so), and use groups to selectively enable access rights.

Comment: It is possible to use SE Linux to restrict "root" accounts: see http://www.coker.com.au/selinux/play.html for a demonstration.  However, traditional UNIX permissions are still much easier to set up.